# not sure how to use a signal from a sensor to make a lightbulb turn on or off

Tags: electrical-engineering

I am a very new student of engineering. I am in high school. The problem is my grandpa has an obsession with checking to see if the garage door is closed. So my dad is trying to get me to develop a solution. So far I have the idea of using photoelectric tripwire sensor to sense if the door is closed. But, I have no idea how to get the signal out of the sensor and to the lightbulb, or how to get the lightbulb to receive the signal.

Comment: Are you located in US, Canada, Europe, or Asia? Is the current garage door automated?

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to SE Engineering. If my dad gave me this task, I would do the following:

Use any common variety reed switch sensor, you have probably seen them at Home Depot or your local hardware store. They come as a pair, you get a magnet assembly which mounts to the door and a molded reed switch which mounts to the door frame such that when the door opens the switch closes completing a separate circuit , in your case the separate circuit would be the coil of a relay which would turn a light on when the door is open. I will leave it for you to work out the electronic details, use LED's as your light source so you can use low voltages. You can find a myriad of such circuits online. You will have to play with the relative positions of the sensor and magnet so that the light only comes on when the door is not completely shut. Have fun !

Comment: Even a simple spring loaded switch pushed by the door when it is in the closed position would work, just like the door switches used for car interior lights.

Comment: Yes Solar Mike, that would work too, but they wear out faster than non contact sensors.

Answer (score 2):

If you are very new to all of this, I think my recommendation would be to start with an electronics learner kit.  For example something like this: [https://www.amazon.com/Elenco-Electronic-Playground-Learning-Center/dp/B0035XSZDI](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0035XSZDI) (just an examples, there are many out there). Most of these will come will guided tutorials on wiring up basic circuits and explain how they work. Look for something that includes switches or sensors and lights/LEDs (i.e. all of the stuff you'll probably need for the garage door projects). Once you have some idea of how circuits work, then try the garage door projects.